# WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found with python3.7.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, dll, ctypes

I tried to load an external dll with Python3.7 but it failed

My env :

- win10 64bit
- python 3.75 64bit

My code :

```py
if path_dll is not None:
    path_dll += "xxxx.dll"
    print(path_dll)
    self.pDll = WinDLL(path_dll)
```

This raises the following error : **the specified module could not be found**

[image: Error]

The same code works on Python3.9.

Why am I getting this error on Python3.7 ?

I already tried change the path to raw, and all other format, but it still failed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] (`print(os.path.isfile(path_dll), path_dll)` could help). Moreover,  [*do not* use images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code.

Answer (score 0):

The "WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found" error typically indicates that Python is unable to locate a specific module or library that is needed to run your code. This can be caused by a number of factors, such as:

Incorrect module or library name: Make sure that you have spelled the name of the module or library correctly and that it is imported correctly in your code.

Missing module or library: If you are using a module or library that is not part of the Python standard library, make sure that it is installed on your system and is available to Python.

Incorrect module or library path: If you are using a module or library from a specific location on your system, make sure that the path to the module or library is correct.

Permissions issue: Make sure that you have the necessary permissions to access the module or library.

To troubleshoot this error, you may want to try the following:

Double-check the name and spelling of the module or library to make sure that it is imported correctly.

Check to see if the module or library is installed on your system and is available to Python.

Check the path to the module or library to make sure it is correct.

Check the permissions on the module or library to make sure that you have the necessary access.

If you are still having trouble after trying these steps, you may want to try searching online for more specific troubleshooting advice or consider seeking help from other Python users or developers.